# Run script with sh or bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, shebang

I have a .sh file. It includes bash syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash
function foo() {
    // do something
}

doo()
// do something
```

sh doesn't link to bash on my system.

Below command doesn't work:

```
sh sample.sh
```

It throws syntax error. Below command works fine.

```
bash sample.sh
```

I think '#!/bin/bash' is useless for my case. I know that sh != bash. But do I must specify sh/bash/etc like upper example to run .sh file?

Comment: `chmod u+x sample.sh; ./sample.sh`?

Comment: `sh yourscript` ignores the shebang line and forces `sh`. Don't use it; just run `./yourscript`.

Comment: "Must I use a shebang or use the correct shell on the command lime?" Yes, one or the other - no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

The [shebang (#!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is only used if you execute the file (i.e: ./sample.sh). Of course, the file must have execution permissions.

If you execute `sh` with your file as argument its content is interpreted by `sh` (not taking into account the shebang). The same for `bash` or any other command that reads the file represented by the first argument.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and therein the bullet point regarding questions which "have been asked and answered many times before".